# Format numbers in java

Tags: java

How do I get these formats in java?

Input:

```
1223893
180703
80967
1461
700
```

Output :

```
1,223,893
180,703
80,967
1,461
700
```

I will be always converting one by one number, this was just to get more examples.

Comment: Solution [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/205639/924824#post924824).

Comment: I believe theres a class for this called NumberFormat

Comment: please avoid links to java 1.4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can read up on java number formatting [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

so you would do something like this:

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat('###,###,###');
String output = myFormatter.format('1223893');
```

if you output the `output` var it should have `1,223,893`

Comment: snap, I just saw in my database I need to insert 1,223,893.00 format, how do I modify for that? I tried adding .## but it doesn't work

Comment: @London look at the link in my post

Answer (score 3):

Look for "grouping" and "thousands separator" [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html). `DecimalFormatSymbols` provides `setGroupingSeparator(',')` and you can set it on a `DecimalFormat`, together with `setGroupingSize(3)`. To illustrate:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().setGroupingSeparator(',');
df.setGroupingSize(3);
System.out.println(df.format(1223893)); // prints 1,223,893
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use  [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

google for NumberFormat in java

See the api [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

Comment: please don't give links to 1.4.2. There's java 6 already for a long time.

Comment: @Bozho @Neal Thanks, I will try to put only references to latest versions

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class.