# Java and decimals E numbers

Tags: java

Java comes up with numbers like *9.870699812169277E-4*

How should I interpret it? Is there a way to parse it in Java and display without that E?

Comment: An example of code that produce that output ? What exactly do you want to do ? It is called exponential notation ...

Comment: And how much is that number? I'm using a few math techniques on minimizing some parameters. I know this should be a very small number, but how small is the question? (I ask how small since I don't know what that exponential notation does to it)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use NumberFormat.

`Code`

```
// you can format to any output you want
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00000000000");
String string = formatter.format(9.870699812169277E-4);
System.out.println(string);
```

`Result`

```
0.00098706998
```

**Related**

[Java: Format double with decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895338/java-format-double-with-decimals) and 
[Format numbers in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656289/format-numbers-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any language which doesn't support this notation (except perhaps machine code)  Even most calculators support it.

I suspect the languages you have used before support this notation, however it just wasn't used.

9.870699812169277E-4 is the same 9.870699812169277 * 10-4 or 0.0009870699812169277

For your interest there is a P notation e.g. `0x1.fffffffffffffP+1023` which is a hex notation for a double.